# Node-red I can't extract the message body

Tags: javascript, node-red

I started using Node-Red to develop an MQTT dashboard,
I just starting with a simple example to subscribe to a topic and debug the message.
However, I couldn't get the json value of my message and convert it from base64 to a string.

my message looks as fellow:

```js
"{"metrics":{},"body":"eyJjb250ZW50LXNwZWMiOiJ1cm46c3BlYzpcL1wvZWNsaXBzZS5vcmdcL3VuaWRlXC9tZWFzdXJlbWVudC1tZXNzYWdlI3YyIiwiZGV2aWNlIjp7ImRldmljZUlEIjoiMTMyNDUifSwibWVhc3VyZW1lbnRzIjpbeyJzZXJpZXMiOnsiJF90aW1lIjpbMF0sIlZBIjpbMjM5MzMwLjBdfSwidHMiOiIyMDE4LTA0LTI1VDA5OjM4OjU0LjIyOCswMDAwIn1dfQ=="}"
```

I want to extract the body message and convert it.

I already tried this function after using a JSONconverter:

```js
return msg.payload.body;
```

but I got his error:
"Function tried to send a message of type string"

[nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1I4f.png)

[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwyer.png)

Best regards

Comment: Hi, please update the question to show what you are trying to do. The title of the question does not appear to relate to the body of the question - is this about connecting to the broker or about getting the value out of a message object?

Comment: Dear knolleary, 
it was my mistake sorry, I updated the title
My real problem is about getting the value out of the message object.

Kindest regards

Comment: Please share the details of what you have tried. You say 'I tried this function'... but you have not provided the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated the code,
the function is simply: return msg.payload.body;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Function node must return a message object - not an plain value. That is why you are getting the error messaging telling you the Function is sending a String.

If you want the payload of the message it sends to be that string value, you would do:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.body;
return msg;
```

For that type of thing, you would be better served using the Change node to *move* `msg.payload.body` to `msg.payload`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got to extract my message body with both methods, however when I extract the message and convert from 64base, I will have a String output, 
How can I convert a string to JSON ? 
thanks a lot for your assistance

Comment: If you have a string representation of JSON, just pass the msg through the JSON node which will return an JSON object